# New to MATLAB. Getting the error First input argument must be a function handle. While attempting to integrate current function

Tags: matlab, function, integral

So this is what I have so far

```
t=60;

q=integral(e(t)*i(t), t, 0, 2*pi);

function v=e(t)

v=160*sin(t);

end

function c=i(t)

c=2*sin(t-(pi/6));

end
```

but it is returning the following errors and I have no idea how to fix it. I've looked at other posts referencing the same error and I haven't been able to fix it.

```
Error using integral (line 82)
First input argument must be a function handle.

Error (line 10)
q=integral(e(t)*i(t), t, 0, 2*pi);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the integral command? It has bunch of working examples that you can easily modify to suit your needs. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like this:

```
e_times_i = @(t) e(t) .* i(t)
q=integral(e_times_i, 0, 2*pi);
```

Indeed, the first argument of `integral` matlab function handle. You gave *value* not the function handle.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm absolutely horribe with MATLAB, but hoping to get better. I incorporated that into my script file, however it is still returning errors.


Error in [name]>e_times_i (line 23)

y = e(t) * i(t);


Error in [name] (line 12)

q=integral(e_times_i, 0, 2*pi);

@Sunghee Yun

Comment: @crisluengo Thank you for the response, I have been attempting that in varying forms, but end up with a massive list of errors when I attempt to call the function in the integration function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but would I also need a handle for the functions within e_times_i?

Comment: @alistenberger I corrected my answer. This should work! I tested in octave. Hope this'd help you!

Comment: @alistenberger My Pleasure! *^^* Great to feel helpful. :)