# New to MATLAB. Getting the error First input argument must be a function handle

Tags: matlab

```
Error using integral (line 82)
First input argument must be a function handle.

Error in matlamprojj (line 35)
surface_area = 2 * pi * integral(integrand, 0, 2*pi);
```

- Evaluate the surface area of the solid of revolution generated by revolving the graph of
  h() around the -axis between 0 and 2.
- Evaluate the volume of the solid of revolution generated by revolving the graph of
  h() around the -axis between −2 and 2

**My code**

```
% Evaluate the surface area using the integral function
surface_area = 2 * pi * integral(integrand, 0, 2*pi);

disp(['Surface Area: ', num2str(surface_area)]);

% Define the integrand for volume
integrand_volume = h(x)^2;

% Evaluate the volume using the integral function
volume = pi * integral(integrand_volume, -2*pi, 2*pi);

disp(['Volume: ', num2str(volume)]);
```

Comment: this is not the full code. In any case, you want a _function handle_, i.e. for `sin`, you want `integrand = @(x)sin(x)`. We can't help more without a [mcve]

Comment: ℎ() =3/2   + sin (/2 ) + cos (/2 ),
where  and  are the maximum and mean values of the digits in your student-ID number.
 
 d) Evaluate the surface area of the solid of revolution generated by revolving the graph of 
 h() around the -axis between 0 and 2.
 e) Evaluate the volume of the solid of revolution generated by revolving the graph of 
 h() around the -axis between −2 and 2

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify the question, don’t try to write important information in comments. The error message complains about the `integrand` argument, so at a minimum show how that is defined in your code. Make sure we can run the code: in a clear MATLAB session, run the code you post here and make sure it produce the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [New to MATLAB. Getting the error First input argument must be a function handle. While attempting to integrate current function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244473/new-to-matlab-getting-the-error-first-input-argument-must-be-a-function-handle)

> the first argument of integral matlab function handle. You gave value not the function handle.

You did not define a function that you are plugging into the integral

See for more information: [Integration - MATLAB & Simulink Example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/integration-featured.html)

Let's solve an example:

[image: \int_{0}^{2^{\pi }}2\pi x^2dx]

Create some curve f(x). Now we need to define it in matlab

```
# We need to create a symbolic scalar to represent x
syms x    
fun = x^2
```

Read more about `syms` at link on bottom of comment.

Now we can pass it to the integral function `int`. Note, `integrate` is not the same as `int`, see link at bottom.

```
surface_area = 2*pi*int(fun,0,2*pi)
```

This should return the surface area of the curve f(x) above. The surface area is `(16*pi)/3`

See output from MATLAB terminal I used to validate:

```
>> syms x
>> fun = x^2
fun =
x^2
>> 2*pi*int(fun,0,2)
ans =
(16*pi)/3
>>
```

Going back to your example, define whatever function you are using by declaring a symbolic scalar and then using the scalar to create a MATLAB function object. Pass that MATLAB function object into the first parameter of the function `int` along with the left and right bounds. Because you are calculating surface area, do not forget `2*pi` to be added to the integration.

[More information on syms](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html)

[LaTeX Equation Editor because this is not math stack exchange](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?%5Cdpi%7B110%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%7D2%5Cpi&space;x%5E2dx)

[Link for Math where I refreshed on how to calculate surface area](https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-calculus-concepts/section/6.7/primary/lesson/area-of-a-surface-of-revolution-calc/)

[MATLAB - `int` is not the same as `integrate`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/524284-what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-integral)